# Interpolate and match missing values between two dataframes of different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gis

I'm new to pandas and python in general.

Currently I'm trying to interpolate and make the coordinates of two different dataframes match. The data comes from two different GEOTIFF files from the same source, one being temperature and the other being radiation. The file was converted to pandas with georasters.

The radiation dataframe has more points and data, I want to upscale the temperature dataframe and have the same coordinates as the prior.

Radiation Dataframe:

|  | row | col | value | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 197 | 2427 | 5.755 | -83.9325 | 17.5075 |
| 1 | 197 | 2428 | 5.755 | -83.93 | 17.5075 |
| 2 | 197 | 2429 | 5.755 | -83.9275 | 17.5075 |
| 3 | 197 | 2430 | 5.755 | -83.925 | 17.5075 |
| 4 | 197 | 2431 | 5.755 | -83.9225 | 17.5075 |

1850011 rows × 5 columns

Temperature Dataframe:

|  | row | col | value | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 59 | 725 | 26.8 | -83.9583 | 17.5083 |
| 1 | 59 | 726 | 26.8 | -83.95 | 17.5083 |
| 2 | 59 | 727 | 26.8 | -83.9417 | 17.5083 |
| 3 | 59 | 728 | 26.8 | -83.9333 | 17.5083 |
| 4 | 59 | 729 | 26.8 | -83.925 | 17.5083 |

167791 rows × 5 columns

[Source of data](https://globalsolaratlas.info/download/honduras)
"Gis data - LTAym_AvgDailyTotals (GeoTIFF)"

**Temperature Map**
[image: Temperature Map]

**Radiation (GHI) Map**
[image: Radiation (GHI) Map]

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to change the information of a column, you have to use iloc. I said I gave the fourth column from the left and index 3, which is the same as column x, then I gave it your values, then I printed the result.

`import pandas as pd


Radiation = {'row':["197","197","197","197","197"],
         'col':["2427","2428","2429","2430","2431"],
         'value':['5.755','5.755','5.755','5.755','5.755'],
         'x':['-83.9325','-83.93','-83.9275','-83.925','-83.9225'],
         'y':['17.5075','17.5075','17.5075','17.5075','17.5075']
}

Temperature = { 'row':["59","59","59","59","59"],
                'col':["725","726","727","728","729"],
                'value':["26.8","26.8","26.8","26.8","26.8"],
                'x':["-83.9583","-83.95","-83.9417","-83.9333","-83.925"],
                'y':["17.5083","17.5083","17.5083","17.5083","17.5083"]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Radiation)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Temperature)
df1.iloc[4:,3]='1850011'
df2.iloc[4:,3]='167791'
Comparison = df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
print(df1)
print(df2)`